# jQuery Video height & width on different devices?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, video

So i have a video in side a div and i'm calling it using jquery, my problem is i want the video to fill the div on different screen sizes.

Here's my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#viddiv').append('<video src="1.mp4"  type="video/mp4" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" </video>');`
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div id="viddiv">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And my CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
video {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #viddiv {
        height: 768px;
        width: 1024px;
        background-color:#FF0;
           }    
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

   #viddiv {
        height: 1024px;
        width: 768px;
        background-color:#00F;
           }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

   #viddiv {
        height: 480px;
        width: 640px;
        background-color:#0F0;
           }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

    #viddiv {
        height: 480px;
        width: 640px;
        background-color:#F00;
           }
}
```

Really cant work it out i'm sure as ever this is easy to do.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    $('#viddiv').append('<video src="1.mp4"  type="video/mp4" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" </video>')
.css({"width":screen.width, "height":screen.height});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GtpEC/)

Comment: Thanks its making the video smaller in dreamweaver when i preview it but not in chrome :( guess i'll need to actually get it on a device to see how it looks - many thanks